# Same formula, different results?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

You are my last chance to find a solution :
I have 2 cells (`C6 & D6`; `08:00:00 & 12:26:00`) and a simple formula (`=D6-C6`). This one is working properly but I have another one (`=IF(OR(C6="JF";C6="WE");"00:00";D6-C6)`) which is quite simple but as you can see on this photo :

To help understand: [image]

The result of this second formula is not quite the same as the first one...which is weird as they have the same end (`D6-C6`)...I need either an explanation of why and a solution to have the 4:26 end on the second formula.

I've tried this one : (`=SI(OU(C6<>"JF";C6<>"WE");D6-C6;"00:00:00")`) but the result is the same (`0,184722222`).

Comment: In the "Formulas" tab, there is a button "Evaluate Formulas", which evaluates your formula step by step. This might show you at which point you don't get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong per se. It's a case of format being different. I think the easiest way here would be to make use of the format painter:

1. Click on the cell with the format to copy (the one with the time)
2. Click the format painter
3. Click on the cell you want to format (the one with the decimal)

[image]

Otherwise format the cell with the decimal as time:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the same value but with different format. Just change the cell format to hh:mm:ss

> Check [Format numbers as dates or
>   times](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309#bm1)